# Issue with height when trying to set up grid css for web panel

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid using grid css. I am having issue when setting 100vh, whenever I set the height to 100vh I can scroll down, which I do not want to happen. How can I get rid of the scroll? Also when trying to set for mobile the view doesn't look well, am I doing something wrong? I want the nav and menu to be fixed, and make the content page only scrollable.

`"Content-Area Content-Area Content-Area";`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Navbar Navbar Navbar"
    "SideNav Content-Area Content-Area";
}

.Navbar { grid-area: Navbar; background-color: blue; }

.SideNav { grid-area: SideNav; background: green; height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto; }

.Content-Area { grid-area: Content-Area; }

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Navbar">tester</div>
  <div class="SideNav">tea</div>
  <div class="Content-Area">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow-y: hidden;` to the `<body>` tag seems to do the trick.

I also added

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

to clear margin and padding from all elements to form a starting point. Not necessary for this example, but still a good stating point.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Navbar Navbar Navbar" "SideNav Content-Area Content-Area";
}

.Navbar {
  grid-area: Navbar;
  background-color: blue;
}

.SideNav {
  grid-area: SideNav;
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.Content-Area {
  grid-area: Content-Area;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Navbar">tester</div>
  <div class="SideNav">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum in nisi tristique, mollis neque eu, pretium mi. Curabitur ut rutrum est, vitae faucibus nunc. Nam ullamcorper purus sed elit mollis elementum. Phasellus lorem velit, auctor et elit eget,
    dapibus sollicitudin enim. Suspendisse interdum turpis eu mauris vehicula, et maximus nunc aliquam. Sed tincidunt venenatis dui vitae scelerisque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc nec
    laoreet ipsum. Vivamus eu fringilla tortor. Integer vulputate, ex quis pretium rhoncus, lorem turpis iaculis ante, non porttitor ex sem at urna. Sed tristique ante non ante commodo, eget vestibulum ligula sodales. Cras at erat dapibus, luctus neque
    eget, pellentesque dolor. Mauris in augue luctus, vulputate nunc sed, tristique ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc vitae ipsum suscipit, aliquet nulla eget, scelerisque lacus. Curabitur
    ligula tellus, varius sit amet suscipit non, faucibus at tellus. Cras at sapien urna. Curabitur ex eros, ultricies at ante vel, dapibus rhoncus mauris. Proin pulvinar, magna sed feugiat dapibus, mauris velit molestie massa, a volutpat sem augue a
    nunc. Donec placerat felis nec urna elementum dignissim. Aliquam non tortor sollicitudin, eleifend ex ac, venenatis libero. Nullam interdum euismod odio, eget blandit diam faucibus at. Curabitur luctus interdum blandit. Donec sed dui vehicula, aliquet
    risus eget, condimentum tellus. Suspendisse ac orci felis. Sed varius ipsum ante, nec viverra urna congue ac. Phasellus euismod at erat et pulvinar. Donec vehicula et mauris vitae luctus. Nulla vitae consectetur eros, ac porttitor nisl. Phasellus
    in turpis sed diam facilisis bibendum nec in est. Aenean sit amet pretium quam, id egestas sem. Mauris lacinia condimentum leo non ultricies. Fusce commodo sagittis risus vel tristique. Fusce vulputate ultrices pellentesque. Praesent eu metus arcu.
    Integer convallis finibus sapien, sit amet laoreet lectus sagittis sit amet. Vivamus eu mattis nisl. Morbi non vehicula sem. Donec hendrerit, enim a commodo viverra, risus urna fringilla orci, eu tincidunt risus nibh ut mi. Morbi eu posuere massa.
    Morbi consectetur massa eget pretium imperdiet. Curabitur pretium congue ante ut imperdiet. Vivamus fermentum, augue sit amet varius tempor, nisl odio dignissim mauris, nec sagittis lacus nisl eu sapien. Aliquam enim orci, sagittis et odio sed, aliquet
    luctus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse elementum consequat ipsum quis vestibulum. Mauris lobortis scelerisque ipsum nec faucibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus a turpis est. Nam at mi sit
    amet odio pretium auctor sit amet a eros. Sed ante ex, molestie a quam nec, feugiat ullamcorper dolor. Morbi non rhoncus urna. Aenean varius euismod tristique. Duis dui leo, hendrerit eu dapibus vitae, faucibus vitae magna.
  </div>
  <div class="Content-Area">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sidenav sits below the navbar, so the height of navbar is being added to the 100vh height, which makes the whole page overflow vertically.

Instead of setting the height of sidenav explicitly you can allow its contents to determine its height, then update `grid-template-rows` to `auto 1fr`

For the scrolling behaviour you described, I added `body { overflow: hidden; }`, `.container { max-height: 100vh; }` and  `.Content-Area { overflow: auto; }`

Here’s the final version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <style>

         body {
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
         }

         .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
            gap: 0px 0px;
            /*grid-auto-flow: row;*/
            grid-template-areas:
               "Navbar Navbar"
               "SideNav Content-Area";
            max-height: 100vh;
         }

         .Navbar {
            background-color: blue;
            grid-area: Navbar;
         }

         .SideNav {
            background: green;
            grid-area: SideNav;
            height: 100vh;
         }

         .Content-Area {
            font-size: 80px;
            grid-area: Content-Area;
            overflow: auto;
         }

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="Navbar">NAVBAR</div>
         <div class="SideNav">SIDENAV</div>
         <div class="Content-Area">

            Nam qui soluta autem accusantium ex magnam voluptatem. Minima quisquam enim incidunt. Voluptatem autem est temporibus libero quae. Qui est et sint cum dolorem cupiditate.

            Est eum nemo provident omnis ut facilis temporibus. Qui incidunt similique unde. Voluptatem velit tempora provident eaque. Dolore velit consequatur enim deleniti sapiente deleniti est. Ratione sint eveniet perspiciatis illo. Nostrum exercitationem omnis culpa architecto ut.

         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it's ok only whenever I set navbar height to 30px for e.g and then do `height: calc(100vh - 30px)`. But how do I calculate the height of navbar when the height is being set by content?

Comment: I'll add another answer below because there is another problem with your `grid-template-areas`

EDIT Actually I will edit my previous answer!

Comment: Just updated my answer above with a complete example. If you want to set an exact height for navbar you can do that with, for example, `.Navbar { height: 200px; }` and the browser will do the calculation to make sidenav and content fill the remaining height.

`fr` units are really handy!